# why is smalltalk the second most love programming language

Tags: smalltalk

[smalltalk second most loved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AegY.png)

What is smalltalk used for that makes it so popular?
Where can I learn some basic smalltalk?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [ask].

Comment: i believe you should be able to google this.

Comment: for the second question: there are plenty of resources to learn smalltalk. (look for pharo and squeak).

Comment: @lurker it is in the 2017 survey: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is smalltalk used for is searchable (lots of banks and related institutions), but it won't answer your question.

most loved doesn't mean most popular, but i think it means the satisfaction of its users.

to understand the graph you need to look at the constituents of the smalltalk user base.

smalltalk is an old language that was popular in the 80s and early 90s, but it was to expensive then to be picked up by developers themselves.

so at that time the only opportunity to learn smalltalk was on jobs where the employer paid for the license.

anyone who dreaded smalltalk then, would have switched jobs a long time ago. what remains is the people who love it.

why they fall in love with it is not answerable objectively and thus not really a suitable topic here. go learn smalltalk to find out for yourself :-)

today smalltalk is available freely, but there are no jobs for junior developers. as a result, the only way to get into smalltalk is as a hobby, and so people who don't like it will stop using it before they reach a point where they could dread it, which i'd expect only happens when you have no choice to use the language at work. only those who love it stick to it long enough that they get the experience needed to pick up one of the few available smalltalk jobs.